# Handling form re-validation with a file upload with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using a PHP server-side script to handle image uploads to my server, similar to [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). I'll copy it here (this is not my actual script, it's very similar though):

Client-side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Server-side:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

This works fine, except for one little quirk in a situation when the user picks an image and clicks `Upload` but some other field in the form doesn't get validated, so the form has to load back up with an error. In that situation I prefer to re-load all the fields that the user had already filled out (for a better user-experience.)

But what is the process to keep a previously uploaded file/image after such re-validation?

Answer (score 0):

In short, this cannot be done. Allowing a web page to prefill file upload fields with data would present significant security concerns. You will need to find a workaround to give the impression of "prefilling" the file upload field. Namely, some kind of text field giving the filename they originally uploaded, and a 'overwrite file' checkbox that brings up a new file upload field when checked.

Comment: Thanks. This means that I will have to somehow store that uploaded file on the server (temporarily) right? The question is though, how would I delete those temp files if the user cancels the upload?